# XPath to retrieve text within span

Tags: html, xpath, xpath-2.0

I am trying to figure out the XPath which will retrieve the 'text Data 3' from the following HTML snippet

```
  <span class="inner-span">
    Text-data 1
    <br>
    <span>Text Data 2</span> text Data 3
   </span>
```

So far i have tried the following Xpath which leads me to the span with class 'inner-span'

```
 /html/body/div/div[4]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/span[@class="inner-span"]
```

But dont know what to add more to Xpath which will only give me text 'text Data 3' from above Html snippet.
Thanks

Answer (score 14):

For your particular case this XPath query would work:

```
normalize-space(//span[@class="inner-span"]/text()[last()])
```

Tried it in this [online tester](http://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html) and here's the result:

1. Your HTML;
2. My XPath expression;
3. The expected result "text Data 3".

[image]

Comment: I checked your solution on the same link you provided but it gives all text-data from [@class="inner-span"]. I just want text data 3, not all text data 1,text data 2,text data 3.

Comment: I've added a screenshot to show you the result I got and how I got it, hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You could select `/html/body/div/div[4]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/span[@class="inner-span"]/text()[last()]` to get the text node (though with leading and trailing white space) or you can use an XPath returning a string with `normalize-space(/html/body/div/div[4]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/span[@class="inner-span"]/text()[last()])`.